# Custom Redirect based on Customer Group

Tags: magento-1.7, customer, redirect

I have installed an extension that allows me to prevent certain customer groups from accessing certain products/categories.

E.x. Only my retailer customers have access to product displays etc.

When a retail user logs in and clicks the category link for those products, they are sent to that page. Any customer not logged in or not belonging to that group is redirected to the "404 Page Not Found" page.

My question is where can I change this action to redirect to a page of my choosing?

Currently on version 1.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Magento allows for either redirect to customer account dashboard or the last page the user visited.

You can either choose to write your own extension or use a free [extension](http://www.magepsycho.com/custom-login-redirect.html) from MagePsycho.
I've used the extension once a while back, from what I can remember it worked pretty well.

If you rather write your own extension observer the `customer_login` event which is called just after the active (logged in) customer is set. The event data contains the customer object from which you can obtain it's customer group which you can then use to redirect on.

Comment: While I will probably use that extension in the future, I am not really looking to redirect when they log in. When customers that do not have access to a certain category click on the link to it, they are redirected to a 404 error page. I would like to change that so they are redirected to a page with information on how they can gain access.

Comment: my bad, I misread your question. In that case the 404 is thrown by the extension you're using and displaying a different page will require you to modify the extension on the point where it redirects to the 404 page